# Cut of a specific part of a string with variable lenght and update it into another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table A that contains 2 columns - 1 of em with entries. In column 1 campaign-name . In column 2 i Want to insert a specific part of the campaign-name. Sound really simple, but the lenght of the campaign-name is variabe (but the structure is always the same)...

Here´s an example:

For example if the table A contained (till now):

```
|col1                           ||col2          |
+-------------------------------+---------------+
|17_0102_LC_UpBirthday_LCAll_DE ||              |
|17_0102_News_Luxus_1_DE        ||              |
|17_0105_News_SDT_1_DE          ||              |
|17_0108_LC_UpBirthday_LCAll_NL ||              |
```

I want a query that will "produce":

```
|col1                           ||col2          |
+-------------------------------+---------------+
|17_0102_LC_UpBirthday_LCAll_DE ||LC_UpBirthday |
|17_0102_News_Luxus_1_DE        ||News_Luxus    |
|17_0105_News_SDT_1_DE          ||News_SDT      |
|17_0108_LC_UpBirthday_LCAll_NL ||LC_UpBirthday |
```

-> I allways want the part between the second and forth '_' of the string

This what I got so far (must be sth. that works with substring & instr I recon):

UPDATE A SET col2  =  SUBSTRING(col1, INSTR(col1, '_');

-> but of course, this is not working, it´s just a solution approach ...

Comment: Maybe I got it already... is this correct?     UPDATE A SET col2 = `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`col1`, '_', -2),'_', 2)`

Comment: Test it, and if so you can answer your own question.

Comment: was just a bit wrong: SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '_', -4),'_', 2) is correct :*